# Ground and power polygons on 2 layer PCB

Tags: pcb

I am designing a 2 layer PCB with very low component density. This PCB will be used to mass-test some other PCB. It has many ADCs, a DC/DC converter, I2C traces and Power-MOSFETs to turn on currents up to 2 amps.
I have already read most of the discussion on this topic on internet, but have not come to a sufficient answer. I read one answer that makes sense and straight afterwards read another that contradicts the first one and also makes sense.
So my question is, what would be the best technic for ground and power wiring on my PCB?

Comment: The best can't be determined as we don't know what options you have. The solution is always a compromise between multiple goals.